# PHP: Get strings between string A and string B (multiple strings need to be searched for)

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have one large string which goes like this:

```
$string = '<span id="nothread307693965">blabla here is a lot of text blabla<span id="nothread5248574987">blabla even more text<span id="nothread9754541">';
```

I now need to get all the numbers from the threads. ('' --> '307693965'). For this I need a stringbetween search in PHP which should return all the numbers in an array.

Output should be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(307693965)
  [1]=>
  int(5248574987)
  [2]=>
  int(9754541)
}
```

This is the place I'm stuck, please help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string functions. But for extraction purposes a simple regular expression is advisable for minimal structure verification:

```
 preg_match_all('/[\s]id="nothread(\d+)"/', $html, $result);
 $numbers = $result[1];
```

The `\s` means space. And the `\d+` matches decimals. The `( )` braces are used for capturing, and because they are the first, their content will show up in index `[1]` of the result array.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/nothread([0-9]{5,})/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches` now contains what you wanted.