# get DomXPath value by attribute "name"

Tags: php, domdocument, html, domxpath

I'm trying to get CIK codes from [EDGAR](http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar).  They don't give `id`s to their elements, but they at least give a `name`.

In this case, when there's a result, the page will have a `hidden` with `name="CIK"`.

I've got the page in a `DOMDocument` and that in a `DomXPath`.  How do I get the value of that field?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple once you wind your way through the docs.

`$CIK = $finder->query("//hidden[@name='CIK']");`

Oh, I wouldn't use that though.  Their `html` is nothing but a mess and gave errors all over the place.

---

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920893/1382306) instead.

Comment: Every one shouting out "do not use preg regexp to parse html". :) I think the best way is a way that you know..